# LLVM LoopInfo in FunctionPass doesn't compile

Tags: llvm, llvm-clang

i'm starting to learn llvm api and i wrote my first pass.
My goal is to print how functions call each others.

Lately i wanted to add some loop information to the display to look if a function can be call several time or not. But when i try to use LoopInfo i got this compilation error :

```
llvm[0]: Compiling cfg.cpp for Debug+Asserts build (PIC)
In file included from cfg.cpp:19:
In file included from /home/llvm-lab/llvm/include/llvm/Pass.h:378:
  /home/llvm-lab/llvm/include/llvm/PassAnalysisSupport.h:56:37: error:
        no member named 'ID' in 'llvm::LoopInfo'
      return addRequiredID(PassClass::ID);
                                  ^
cfg.cpp:33:10: note: in instantiation of function template
      specialization 'llvm::AnalysisUsage::addRequired<llvm::LoopInfo>'
      requested here
      AU.addRequired<LoopInfo>();
         ^
1 error generated.
```

Here is my code :

```
#include "llvm/ADT/Statistic.h"
#include "llvm/IR/Function.h"
#include "llvm/Support/raw_ostream.h"
#include "iostream"
#include "llvm/Pass.h"
#include "llvm/IR/InstIterator.h"
#include <llvm/IR/Instructions.h>
#include <llvm/Analysis/LoopInfo.h>

using namespace llvm;


namespace {
  struct CFG : public FunctionPass {
    static char ID; // Pass identification, replacement for typeid
    CFG() : FunctionPass(ID) {}

    void getAnalysisUsage(AnalysisUsage &AU) const override {
      AU.addRequired<LoopInfo>();
    }

    bool runOnFunction(Function &F) override {
      errs().write_escaped(F.getName());

      errs() << " : ";

      for( Function::iterator b = F.begin() , be = F.end(); b != be; ++b){
        errs() << "\n\t BB : ";
        LoopInfo *loop = new LoopInfo();
        bool isLoop = loop->getLoopFor(b);
        if(isLoop){
          errs() << "loop{";
        }
        for(BasicBlock::iterator i = b->begin() , ie = b->end(); i!=ie; ++i){
          if( isa<CallInst>(&(*i)) || isa<InvokeInst>(&(*i))){
            errs() << cast<CallInst>(&(*i))->getCalledFunction()->getName() << "\t";
          }
        }
        if(isLoop){
          errs() << "}";
        }
     }

     errs() << '\n';
     return false;
   }



  };
}

char CFG::ID = 0;
static RegisterPass<CFG> X("CFG", "Gen CFG",true ,true);
```

I can't find any reference to an "no member named 'ID' in 'llvm::LoopInfo'" error anywhere, does anyone have an idea about what's is wrong here ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

### Why your code could not be build

`AU.addRequired<typename passclass>()` need a type of `LLMV::Pass`, however what you pass in is `LoopInfo`, which is just an LLVM internal class for loop information maintenance. It does not has a field `ID`.

### `LoopInfoWrapperPass` should be used instead

If you want to get the loop information. Try to change it to `AU.addRequired<LoopInfoWrapperPass>` as shown in the [LLVM Write a new Pass document](http://llvm.org/docs/WritingAnLLVMPass.html#example-implementations-of-getanalysisusage). `LoopInfoWrapperPass` is used to generate `LoopInfo`.

### `LoopInfo` should be get from the pass

There is also a problem in your code about how to get the `LoopInfo`, you are trying to use `new` to create a `LoopInfo`, what you get will be an empty `LoopInfo`.

### The "should work" code for your question

Following is a modified version of your code, which could printout expected informations.

```
#include "llvm/ADT/Statistic.h"
#include "llvm/IR/Function.h"
#include "llvm/Support/raw_ostream.h"
#include "iostream"
#include "llvm/Pass.h"
#include "llvm/IR/InstIterator.h"
#include <llvm/IR/Instructions.h>
#include <llvm/Analysis/LoopInfo.h>


using namespace llvm;


namespace {
  struct CFG : public FunctionPass {
    static char ID; // Pass identification, replacement for typeid
    CFG() : FunctionPass(ID) {}

    void getAnalysisUsage(AnalysisUsage &AU) const override {
      AU.setPreservesCFG();
      AU.addRequired<LoopInfoWrapperPass>();
    }
    bool runOnFunction(Function &F) override {
      LoopInfo &LI = getAnalysis<LoopInfoWrapperPass>().getLoopInfo();
      errs().write_escaped(F.getName());
      errs() << " : ";
      for( Function::iterator b = F.begin() , be = F.end(); b != be; ++b){
        errs() << "\n\t BB : ";
        bool isLoop = LI.getLoopFor(b);
        if(isLoop){ 
          errs() << "loop{";
        }
        for(BasicBlock::iterator i = b->begin() , ie = b->end(); i!=ie; ++i){
          if( isa<CallInst>(&(*i)) || isa<InvokeInst>(&(*i))){
            errs() << cast<CallInst>(&(*i))->getCalledFunction()->getName() << "\t";
          }
        }
        if(isLoop){ 
          errs() << "}";
        }
     }
     errs() << '\n';
     return false;
   }
  };
}

char CFG::ID = 0;
static RegisterPass<CFG> X("CFG", "Gen CFG",true ,true);
```

For the following code feed to LLVM `opt`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define ARRAY_SIZE 100

int foo(int* a , int n) {
  int i;
  int sum = 0;
  for (; i < n; i++) {
    sum += a[i];
  }
  return sum;
}


int main() {
  int a[ARRAY_SIZE] = {1};

  int sum = foo(a, ARRAY_SIZE);

  printf("sum:0x%x\n", sum);
  return 0;
}
```

The output will be:

```
foo : 
     BB : 
     BB : loop{}
     BB : loop{}
     BB : loop{}
     BB : 
main : 
     BB : llvm.memset.p0i8.i64  foo printf
```

Comment: Works great, thanks ! Now i feel a little bit stupid, but really thanks you i was stucked on this for far too long :)

Comment: Thanks, saved me a lot of time!. Interestingly enough, I got the same problem when porting a pass from an old version of LLVM into 3.6.2, it seems that the old versions were ok without the wrappers.